# Xcode 11.5: Build works for everyone on dev team except for one machine ("-L-L" directory prefix during Pod linking)?

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

We have a React Native 0.62.2 mobile app repo that uses CocoaPods and (supposedly) auto-linked packages for our iOS build. Everyone on our team has Xcode 11.5 and CocoaPods 1.9.3 on our machines (all running macOS Catalina 10.15.5).

Our repo's project builds for all of them except for on one machine. For that machine, the build reliably breaks specifically when it comes time to link Pods.

We have also noticed that in the build error output, instead of just a single '-L' prefix before the `/Users/<HOMEDIR>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...` paths like we would expect for typical file linking, we actually see it doubled to '-L-L' (see screenshot below).

[image: Error Screenshot]

We have confirmed that these generated DerivedData directories and products exist.

What could be causing this build issue on just one machine; could it be attributed to the doubled '-L' directory prefix; and what is a possible solution?